# Why is a protected top-level class not allowed?

Tags: java, protected

In Java, why is a protected top-level class not allowed? I've heard answers along the lines of, "It doesn't make sense," but why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't you have a protected abstract class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160019/why-cant-you-have-a-protected-abstract-class-in-java)

Comment: check out [package-private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470556/pros-and-cons-of-package-private-classes-in-java), I was looking for a protected top level class for modularity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you could never access it, so it'd be pointless.

protected is about giving subclasses of the **containing type** access to a member, if there's no containing type, what would it mean? <-- hence pointless.

Comment: but it also allows it to be accessible from within the package